# Are there any web application security standards?

Tags: web-application, appsec

Are there any web application security standards that I can use as a baseline for the security related requirements for a web application, web service, and for  applications supported/hosted by third parties?

How is security risk managed for web application and what are the preventive and corrective controls that I should expect to see?

Additionally, how can we provide security compliance for web applications?

From my findings I found that most organizations have developed their own standards/guidelines like

- [Protecting Web Applications and Users](http://www.asd.gov.au/publications/csocprotect/protecting_web_apps.htm#frame)

Am I mistaken in that there is no universal standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Austria we have a standard more or less written by SecConsult which is loosely based on OWASP documents. You can find more information on it here: http://www.a7700.org/index_e.html

Answer (score 9):

From what I understand there is no 'universal' standard, however several standards do exist that you can use as a point of reference.

- The National Institute of Standards and Technology [NIST] offers [Publication 800-53](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_Special_Publication_800-53)
- If you are dealing with healthcare
  information there is the [HIPAA](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/srsummary.html) set of standards
- If you keep
  credit card information there is the [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/) set of standards
- Finally there is a more generic OWASP [Application Security
  Verification Standard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project)

These are just a few I know about. The standards you build for yourself will be dictated by the nature of your application and the information is serves/stores. However the above resources should help you get an idea of what things you might want to keep in mind or work into your own standard.

Comment: There are also regulators like the FFIEC, Monetary Authority of Singapore (MAS), and others. These are generally at a process and procedure level, dealing with how an organization should run itself and its systems.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on a specific use case (type of industry, country regulations etc.) a web application may be required to satisfy requirements from a variety of different standards. Some worth mentioning standards are the following:

- OWASP Application Security Verification Standard 4.0.3
- National Institute of Technologies Special Publication 800–218
- International Organization for Standardization 27034
- Center for Internet Security Critical Security Control 16: Application Software Security

Apart from formal standards you might want to take a look at projects like OWASP Top Ten or CWE/SANS Top 25.